# MySQL database point-in-time recovery with mysqlpump, possible?

Tags: mysql, backup

We have some medium size MySQL databases (500 GB) on Oracle MySQL community edition, version 5.7.30.

How can we perform point-in-time recovery with mysqlpump?

It doesn't seem to have any option to specify binary log information in the dumped data like mysqldump or mydumper does.

However, neither mysqldump nor mydumper fits well our situation.
mysqldump is single threaded and too slow for us.
mydumper has only "standard" gzip compression, which wastes too much space and in addition, if compression is requested, takes all CPU resources which is causing monitoring alerts.
With external compressor utility I can limit number of cores used, but I don't know how to pipe mydumper output to an external utility.
There is currently no space available to handle uncompressed backup which could be compressed later. Also, this then is a two step process, dump first, compress later.

Answer (score 1):

The following methods only work if the Database has binary logging enabled

#### METHOD #1 : Dump During Downtime

Step 1 : Stop all writes to the Database

Step 2 : Run `FLUSH TABLES; FLUSH BINARY LOGS;`

Step 3 : Run `SHOW MASTER STATUS;` and record the Binary Log Filename and Position in a text file

Step 4 : Launch [mysqlpump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlpump.html) with [--single-transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlpump.html#option_mysqlpump_single-transaction) --set-gtid-purged=AUTO

Step 5 : Start up all your writes

#### METHOD #2 : Dump from a Replica (or Slave) with Binary Logging Enabled

Step 1 : Run `STOP REPLICA;` (or `STOP SLAVE;`)

Step 2 : Run `FLUSH TABLES; FLUSH BINARY LOGS;`

Step 3 : Run `SHOW MASTER STATUS;` and record the Binary Log Filename and Position in a text file

Step 4 : Launch [mysqlpump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlpump.html) with [--single-transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlpump.html#option_mysqlpump_single-transaction) --set-gtid-purged=AUTO

Step 5 : Run `START REPLICA;` (or `START SLAVE;`)

#### NOTES

Please note that the binary log filename and filesize make up the replication coordinates at any given moment in time. This is why recording the filename and position is what you need to do prior to running [mysqlpump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlpump.html).

If you wish to setup replication without GTID you can run

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
   MASTER_LOG_FILE='binarylogfilefromStep3'
  ,MASTER_LOG_POS=binlogpostionfromStep3
...
```

If you are setting up replication with GTID, you don't need the coordinates. Just use

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
...
...
   AUTO_POSITION=1;
```

Comment: Thanks for step by step explanation. Will evaluate this approach vs uncompressed mydumper run.

Comment: Can I swap steps 4 and 5, that is, restart replication before actual backup has been made? That's because we already have noted and saved master status.

Comment: @shpokas please do not do that. If you do, the —single-transaction reference point moves ahead of the master status. This can instantly introduce error 1032 or 1146 problems when starting replication.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!